# How to get div elements with custom attributes using Nokogiri

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

I have HTML with the body looking like:

```
<body>
   <div class="myclass" dd:meta1="meta data 1" dd:meta2="CD5503253E54"></div>
   <div class="myclass" dd:meta1="meta data 11"></div>
</body>
```

I want to get all the div elements which will have `dd:meta2` attributes, so in the above body, I will get just one div.

I wrote code to get the div element, but I am getting an error which looks like it's related to the `:` I have in the attribute.

My logic:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(html_string)
meta_data_divs = page.css('body').css("div[dd:meta2]")
```

Error:

```
unexpected ':' after '#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fac6b986d58>'
```

How do I handle the ':' in the attribute?

Answer (score 2):

I actually did this just yesterday.  Here was my html:

```
<div data-purpose="video-length">[^>]+<\/div>
```

Here was my nokogiri expression:

```
page.parser.css("div[data-purpose=video-length]").first.try(:text).try(:strip)
```

That took the value I wanted out from inside the div tags and stripped off the extra returns.  The reason for using .try calls is to skip having to have if statements to handle when a nil is returned.  The secret here lies in using [] inside the .css expression: div[data-purpose=video-length].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Nokogiri doesn't know how to handle namespaced parameters. Here's an alternate way of getting the same results:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<body>
  <div class="myclass" dd:meta1="meta data 1" dd:meta2="CD5503253E54"></div>
  <div class="myclass" dd:meta1="meta data 11"></div>
</body>
EOT

doc.search('div').select{ |div| div.attributes.include?('dd:meta2') }
# => [#(Element:0x3fea99895530 {
#       name = "div",
#       attributes = [
#         #(Attr:0x3fea99895508 { name = "class", value = "myclass" }),
#         #(Attr:0x3fea998954f4 { name = "dd:meta1", value = "meta data 1" }),
#         #(Attr:0x3fea998954e0 { name = "dd:meta2", value = "CD5503253E54" })]
#       })]
```

which would return all `div` nodes with a `dd:meta2` parameter.

Similarly you could use the same with `.first` tacked on the end to act like `at`, but it wouldn't be as fast as:

```
doc.search('div').find{ |div| div.attributes.include?('dd:meta2') }
# => #(Element:0x3fea99895530 {
#      name = "div",
#      attributes = [
#        #(Attr:0x3fea99895508 { name = "class", value = "myclass" }),
#        #(Attr:0x3fea998954f4 { name = "dd:meta1", value = "meta data 1" }),
#        #(Attr:0x3fea998954e0 { name = "dd:meta2", value = "CD5503253E54" })]
#      })
```

This will be a little slower than how you were trying it because it'll cause the parser to search the entire document and return all `div` tags, then Ruby will have to sift through the results to find the nodes with the desired parameter. But it'll be infinitely faster than code that raises an exception.

I'd recommend filing a bug report with the Nokogiri team showing them the problem.

---

Heh, after writing that I did a search for `dd:meta2` and ran into [your question on Nokogiri-Talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nokogiri-talk/1c7txs__HoY) which has an answer from the Nokogiri god explaining what is happening, and that has the same solution I suggested. So there you have it.